# separate knockoutjs into separate files and use requirejs to inject the content

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

A view model has got rather large and I want to separate it out into different files.  Here is the structure I want to use:

```
 |- knockout-2.2.0.debug.js
 |- require.js
 |- /App
    |- Property.js
    |- /Property
       |- Fields.js
       |- Model.js
       |- ViewModel.js
```

Now within my Property.js file I have:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        ko: "../knockout-2.2.0.debug"
    },
    baseUrl: "/Scripts/App"
})

require(['ko', 'Property/ViewModel'], function (ko, viewModel) {
    var view = new viewModel.PropertyViewModel();
    console.log(view);
    ko.applyBindings(view);

})
```

Model.js

```
define(['ko'], function(ko) {

    return {
        PropertyModel: function(id, name, note) {
            var s = this;
            s.Id = ko.observable(id);
            s.Name = ko.observable(name);
            s.Note = ko.observable(note);
        }
    };
});
```

Now this is where I get stuck, if I have this within my ViewModel:

```
define(['ko', 'Property/Model', 'Property/Field'], function(ko, model, field) {
    return {
        PropertyViewModel: function () {
            var self = this;

            self.Property = ko.observable(new model.PropertyModel("123", "Test", "note"));
        }
    };
});
```

it works perfect but I really want to move the fields I use (`self.Property`, etc) into a separate file, so in my Field.Js file I have the following:

```
define(['ko'], function(ko) {
    return {
        Property: ko.observable()
    };
});
```

and update the following line:

```
self.Property = ko.observable(new model.PropertyModel("123", "Test", "note"));
```

to

```
field.Property(new model.PropertyModel("123", "Test", "Note"))
```

but when I try to console.log the view model, it's just empty.  Is this something you cannot move out and inject into the ViewModel?  If not, why?

Comment: You don't assign to self.Property?

Comment: Indeed you wouldn't normally but I am testing the concept at the moment so assigned self.Property with a value.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand your question but you say the ViewModel is empty ... of course because you don't add any member, you would see a member if you write something like "self.Property = field.Property;"

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand where you have misunderstood my question.  I am replacing self.Property = ko.observable(new PropertyModel("", "", "") with field.Property(new ProperyModel(...) as it has already been declared in my Field.js as this.Property = ko.observable()

Comment: Matt, if you're just looking to shrink your view model, I'd suggest breaking it into smaller independent view models and using them as child models of one parent model.  Pulling single fields or the ko.observable constructor into it's own file doesn't seem like a very flexible or effective approach. (Take a look at the decorator pattern as another approach you might use.)  That said, I'll try to answer your original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think bert has it right in his comments.  Here are the two issues I see:

The first issue: field.Property *is* a ko.observable, it doesn't *return* a ko.observable.  By calling field.Property(someValue) you're setting the field.Property observable to a new value each time you call it, every time you call it. Said another way, the ko.observable at field.Property exists in only one place; as a property of field.  Calling it from viewModel doesn't make it a property of viewModel.

The second issue: even if field.Property were to return a new ko.observable each time, such as

```
define(['ko'], function(ko) {
    return {
        Property: function() { return ko.observable(); }
    };
});
```

and you modified your call to be

```
//Note the extra parens
field.Property()(new model.PropertyModel('123','Test','Note'));
```

you're still not assigning that return value (the new ko.observable) to the viewModel.  You'd have to do something like:

```
self.myProperty = field.Property()(new model.PropertyModel('123', 'Test','Note'));
```

which is not nearly as readable as simply

```
self.myProperty = ko.observable(new model.PropertyModel('123', 'Test', 'Note'));
```

### A Different Approach

With a slight modification to your code, you can write your models (or modules) each in their own file and nest them into one parent viewModel to make your huge view model more manageable.   Here's a simplification of a pattern that works well for me:

childModel.js

```
define(['ko'], function(ko){
    var childModel = function(data){
        var self = this;

        self.myProperty = ko.observable(data.firstValue);
        self.myOtherProperty = ko.observable(data.secondValue);
    };

    return childModel;
});
```

parentModel.js

```
define(['ko', 'childModel'], function(ko, childModel){
    var parentModel = function(){
        var self = this;

        self.childOne = new childModel({firstValue: 'Test', secondValue: '123'});
        self.childTwo = new childModel({firstValue: 'Two', secondValue: '456'});
    };

    return parentModel;
});
```

main.js

```
requre(['ko','parentModel'], function(ko, parentModel){
    var parent = new parentModel();

    ko.applyBindings(parent);
});
```

html

```
<div>
    <!-- ko with : childOne -->
        <span data-bind="text: myProperty"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: myOtherProperty"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko with : childTwo -->
        <span data-bind="text: myProperty"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: myOtherProperty"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->    
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your post and it looks like you answered my question.  Following a meeting with a colleague yesterday we have decided to take a slightly different approach and use modules and separate the code this way.

Comment: Two years later, this answer still helping people.  Thanks Ryan.